# Remainder of a product of numbers

Tags: chinese-remainder-theorem

When the positive integer N is divided by 6, the remainder is 3. When the positive integer M is divided by 4, the remainder is 1. Which of the following integers could be the remainder when the product of the two numbers, NM, is divided by 12?
Indicate all such integers.
1
3
5
7
9
My approach is N is an odd multiple of 3 -> I represent it as 3n
M can be represented as 4m + 1
N*M=3n*(4m +1)
now N*M / 12 =  3n*(4m +1) /12
n*(4m +1) /4 -> 4nm +n /4  -> n/4 -> n is an odd number so n%4 will be 1 or 3
where did I go wrong?

Comment: Use mathjax to format your question.For mathjax basic tutorials for this website , please click here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/934187

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that $3n$ does not necessarily represent an odd multiple of $3$; this is ensured only when $n$ itself is odd. To represent it unambiguously as an odd multiple of $3$, write N as $3(2n+1)$ instead. Now multiply this with $4m+1$ and you get $MN = (4m+1)(6n+3) = 24mn+12m+6n+3$. Obviously, $24mn \equiv 12n \equiv 0 \mod(12)$, so the whole expression is congruent to $6n+3$ mod($12$) which itself is equal to $3(2n+1)$. In other words, which congruence classes mod(12) are the product of $3$ and an odd number? There are just two: $3$ and $9$.

Comment: can you please explain the last line?

Comment: @Sruthi sure I can try, which part of it would you like explained?